# Show Json data in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, json, dojo, web

I am building Dojo mobile app. I have a Json file like:

```
{
    "Introduction": [
        {
            "title": "Introduction",
            "toolbar": "Page 1",
            "cont, aabitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis nt pellentesque vehicula. Nam ac diam lectus. Aliquam convallis posuere enim.",
        },
        {
            "title": "Introduction",
            "toolbar": "Page 2",
            "contesent vel nisi ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque ut ipsum sit amet eros posuere venenatvis egestas. Sed congue felis at risus congue m",
        }
    ],
    "services": [
        {
            "title": "services",
            "toolbar": "Page 1",
            "content": "Cras adipiscing sapien nec tortor vehicula sit amet vehicula est fring.
        }
    ],
}
```

First I need to read this file. There will be 3 pages involve in it.
First page will show 2 list items "Introduction" and "services". On clicking "Introduction" list item, its page 1 will open. There will be a button in page1. On clicking that button page2 will open.

Same will be the case with "services".
I am trying with `dojo.xhrGet({` and `ItemFileReadStore` but in vain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, you are missing "content" in both "Introduction" objects (see [working example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/FexUa/)):

```
{
    Introduction: 
    [
        {
            title:   "Introduction",
            toolbar: "Page 1",
            content: "cont, aabitant morbi tristique..."
        },
        {
            title:   "Introduction",
            toolbar: "Page 2",
            content: "contesent vel nisi ipsum..."
        }
    ],
    Services: 
    [
        {
            title:   "services",
            toolbar: "Page 1",
            content: "Cras adipiscing sapien nec..."
        }
    ]
};
```